# React router render not getting props

Tags: reactjs

My application requires users to authenticate before they can access specific routes. For this, I am trying to follow react-router's [auth-workflow example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow).

**routes/index.js**

```
 // Private Route
 import PrivateRoute from "../containers/PrivateRoute";

 export default (
     <Switch>
         <Route
             path="/login"
             component={Login}
             exact={true}/>
         <Route
             path="/changePassword"
             component={ChangePassword}
             exact={true}/>
         <PrivateRoute
             path="/groups"
             component={ListGroups}
             exact={true}/>
         <Route
             path="/verify"
             component={VerificationCode}
             exact={true}/>
         <Route component={NoMatch}/>
     </Switch>
);
```

**containers/PrivateRoute**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

import PrivateRoute from "../routes/PrivateRoute";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        jwtTokens: state.auth.jwtTokens,
        email: state.auth.email,
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({}, dispatch);
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(PrivateRoute);
```

**routes/PrivateRoute.js**

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => {
                return (props.isAuthenticated) ? (
                    <Component {...props} />
                ) : (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: "/login",
                            state: {
                                from: props.location
                            }
                        }}
                    />
                );
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

When debugging in Chrome DevTools, when entering the `render` function, I am not getting the full values as I am in `rest`. Screenshots below represent my debugging in Chrome and the values I can see at each stage:

[image]

In the image above, I can see the values; `jwtTokens`, `isAuthenticated`, and `email`. To my knowledge from following examples, using the spread operator on `rest` is how I pass the values to `render` as a param. The next screenshot shows this is not the case:

[image]

I am able to simply use the `rest` param to access the properties but shouldn't I be just as easily be able to access the same values from `props` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The render callback of a `Route` that you are using to render `Component` does not forward props received by the `Route` from outside. It only contains the `location`, `match` and `params` of the route. What you probably wanted to do is to spread `rest` into the `<Component />` rather then the `Route` as a `Route` will not use any of those nor does it expect those props:

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
    return (
        <Route
            render={(props) => {
                return (rest.isAuthenticated) ? (
                    <Component {...props} {...rest} /> {/* add rest here instead */}
                ) : (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: "/login",
                            state: {
                                from: props.location
                            }
                        }}
                    />
                );
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

You also need to check `rest.isAuthenticated` instead of `props.isAuthenticated` for the same reason. `isAuthenticated` will not be in the props passed to the `render` callback.

[Also see in the react-router docs about Route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) about which props will be passed to the `render` callback:

> **Route props**
>
> All three [render methods](https://reacttraining.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods) will be passed the same three route props
>
> - [match](https://reacttraining.com/web/api/match)
> - [location](https://reacttraining.com/web/api/location)
> - [history](https://reacttraining.com/web/api/history)

Comment: Ah okay. I was under the impression that the `Route` **does** forward the props to the `render` method. Alas, I am wrong. Thank you for the link you provided about props that can be accessed, I had not seen that previously